# Access TreeMap entries by string key in JSTL

Tags: jstl, treemap

This is pretty similar to some other questions, but nobody else is working with string keys. So here we go.

I've got a TreeMap with a set of category names, keyed by category ID. The ID is a number (as a String).

I build up the TreeMap with values, then expose it to the page, like so:

```
<%
Map categories = new TreeMap();
...
String categoryId = ...;
String categoryName = ...;
categories.put(categoryId, categoryName);
...
pageContext.setAttribute("categories", categories);
%>
```

Later, I iterate through a series of items which have been assigned to categories. Each item has a .categories collection which contains the IDs of the categories to which it has been assigned. I want to display the names, so I do something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${item.categories}" var="catId">
    ${categories[“${catId}”}
</c:forEach>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't emit anything. Nor does `${categories["${catId}"].value}.`

However, this does:

```
${categories["2"]}
```

Of course, that line isn't actually driven by item data.

I've checked, and the IDs attached to each item do in fact correspond to category IDs; this isn't a data mismatch problem.

So, how do I get my hands on category names when the data attached to items has only IDs?

P.S. I should mention that I'm not a Java programmer -- at all. LAMP is more my style. So modifying classes isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, I misread the question.

Unwrap your `catId` variable:

```
 ${categories[“${catId}”}
```

should be

```
 ${categories[catId]}
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Can't do that. I don't want to show the master list of categories for each item, which is what this code would do. I want, for each item, to show the categories to which it belongs. The foreach must iterate through the item's cateogries, cross-referencing them with the master list.

Comment: I could swear I tried that previously with no luck. But I guess not, because your code works! Thanks very much.